# How do I put the favicon on my demo website on Safari LiveServer?

Tags: html, css, favicon

Hope you're all well.

Recently, I started coding in visual studio code as I'll be changing my career to software development, and as I began with HTML and CSS, I stumbled upon a couple of issues.

The most irritating one so far is a favicon issue. I've done everything I can and favicon still won't show up on my demo website. I even cleared the cache, checked the route path before writing the code, but nothing would help.

I saved the favicon image in the folder named "images" in my main folder called VSCodeTraining. I put the following line under the <head></head> and still nothing happens:

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png">

As I am working on a Mac, is there maybe something to do with the fact I'm not importing it from the Mac's main folder?

Thanks for your help in advance and sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: What does your file structure looks like?

Comment: Hi,

It goes like this:

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        <meta name="description" content="Content" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
      </head>